# Correlated-subquery in INSERT statement - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-insert, amazon-redshift, correlated-subquery

I am trying to populate a table using a query that contains a subquery.

The format is the following:

```
INSERT INTO table_C 
SELECT columns FROM table_A, table_B
```

The subquery is present in one of the columns of the select statement and it refers to "table_A" again (there is a join between table_A and table_B).

Here is the code, but before reading it please consider that the select statement works perfectly if run alone (i.e. with no INSERT):

```
INSERT INTO hypercube_2015 (date, hour, name, rel_val)
SELECT t1.date, t1.hour, t2.name,
        CAST(sum(t1.num) as float)/(SELECT sum(t11.num) FROM hc_num t11 WHERE t11.date = t1.date AND t11.hour = t1.hour)
FROM hc_num t1, names t2
        WHERE date between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
        AND t1.id = t2.id
        GROUP BY t1.date, t1.hour, t2.name
```

The issue is related to the subquery in the 3rd line, in particular to the WHERE condition. If I change it into the following it works:

```
SELECT sum(t11.num) FROM hc_num t11 WHERE t11.date = '2015-01-01' AND t11.hour=0
```

The error message is (I am working on a Redshift db via DBVis):

> [Code: 500310, SQL State: XX000]  Amazon Invalid operation:
>   This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to
>   internal error;

Comment: Since Redshift is a closed source fork of PostgreSQL, you should perhaps ask Amazon. It must be some of their code.

Answer (score 0):

I've got no solution to propose but an answer that explains why you have this error.

On RedShift there are several cases where the optimiser can't resolve a correlated subquery and trigger this error. One of them is precisely your kind of suquery:

> ### Correlated Subquery Patterns That Are Not Supported
>
> The query planner uses a query rewrite method called subquery
>   decorrelation to optimize several patterns of correlated subqueries
>   for execution in an MPP environment. A few types of correlated
>   subqueries follow patterns that Amazon Redshift cannot decorrelate and
>   does not support. Queries that contain the following correlation
>   references return errors:
>
> **References in a GROUP BY column to the results of a correlated subquery. For example:**
>
> ```
> select listing.listid,
> (select count (sales.listid) from sales where sales.listid=listing.listid) as list
> from listing
> group by list, listing.listid;
> ```

Source : [Amazon webservices Correlated Subqueries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html)

In your subquery:

```
(SELECT sum(t11.num) FROM hc_num t11 WHERE t11.date = t1.date AND t11.hour = t1.hour)
```

you do make a reference to `t1.hour` which is present in the final `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY t1.date, t1.hour, t2.name
```

Note that I might have a deeper look at your query later to propose an alternative, if nobody else does. Got no time at the moment.